# pygame moving a user controlled object until key is released?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I have been playing with pygame for a little while now and a stackoverflow veteran gave me some help to better improve my code to move a character around on screen. At the moment each time the key is pressed the character will move, slow down then stop, Only continuing to move when the key is press again. Could anybody help so that the character will decelerate and  stop when the key is released?

thanking you kindly

```
import sys
import pygame
import os
from pygame.locals import *

character = "toon.png"
bg = "bg.jpg"

delta = {
    pygame.K_LEFT: (-10, 0),
    pygame.K_RIGHT: (+10, 0),
    pygame.K_UP: (0, -10),
    pygame.K_DOWN: (0, +10),
    }

class Toon(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(character)
        self.bg = pygame.image.load(bg)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.speed = [2, 2]
        self.area = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect()
    def update(self):
        self.rect = self.rect.move(self.speed)
        if self.rect.left < 0 or self.rect.right > self.area.width:
            self.speed[0] = -self.speed[0]
        if self.rect.top < 0 or self.rect.bottom > self.area.height:
            self.speed[1] = -self.speed[1]

class Main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.setup()
    def setup(self):
        pygame.init()
        size = (self.width, self.height) = (640,360)
        self.black = (0, 0, 0)
        self.bg = pygame.image.load(bg)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, 0, 32)
        self.toon = Toon()
        self.setup_background()
    def setup_background(self):
        self.background = pygame.Surface(self.screen.get_size())
        self.background = self.background.convert()
        self.screen.blit(self.bg, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()
    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.bg, (0, 0))
        self.screen.blit(self.toon.image, self.toon.rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
    def event_loop(self):
        toon = self.toon
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    deltax, deltay = delta.get(event.key, (0, 0))
                    toon.speed[0] += deltax
                    toon.speed[1] += deltay
            toon.speed[0] *= 0.95
            toon.speed[1] *= 0.95
            toon.update()
            self.draw()
            pygame.time.delay(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Main()
    app.event_loop()
```

Comment: Simple - you need to keep track of which direction you want to keep moving in. When a key is pressed, set the direction. If all keys are released, but a direction is still indicated, decelerate in that direction. If your speed is 0 or very close to 0, remove the direction - and now you will be at a stop.

Answer (score 3):

I would just change your `Main.event_loop()` and add the other function to your Main Class, which uses `pygame.key.get_pressed`:

```
def event_loop(self):
    toon = self.toon
    while True:
        self.event_handle()
        toon.speed[0] *= 0.95
        toon.speed[1] *= 0.95
        toon.update()
        self.draw()
        pygame.time.delay(10)

def event_handle(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    # This will allow diagonal movements.. 
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.toon.speed[0] = -10
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.toon.speed[0] = +10
    if key[pygame.K_UP]:
        self.toon.speed[1] = -10
    if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        self.toon.speed[1] = +10
```

The changes:

1. I have added a new function, namely `event_handle` which will handle the events and keys.
2. You'll have noticed that the for event loop, doesn't do any key handling. That's because we are using `pygame.key.get_pressed` which is better suited for the current job.

   - It returns a list of bools of the keys currently pressed. We check by indexing `key` for our desired key (Here arrows).

The effect:
Your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `friction = 1` while `KEYDOWN`, and `friction < 1` when `KEYUP`:

```
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                deltax, deltay = delta.get(event.key, (0, 0))
                toon.speed[0] += deltax
                toon.speed[1] += deltay
                friction = 1
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                friction = 0.95
        toon.speed = [x*friction for x in toon.speed]
```

---

```
import sys
import pygame
import os
from pygame.locals import *

character = "toon.png"
bg = "bg.jpg"

delta = {
    pygame.K_LEFT: (-10, 0),
    pygame.K_RIGHT: (+10, 0),
    pygame.K_UP: (0, -10),
    pygame.K_DOWN: (0, +10),
    }

class Toon(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(character)
        self.bg = pygame.image.load(bg)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.speed = [0, 0]
        self.area = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect()
    def update(self):
        self.rect = self.rect.move(self.speed)
        if self.rect.left < 0 or self.rect.right > self.area.width:
            self.speed[0] = -self.speed[0]
        if self.rect.top < 0 or self.rect.bottom > self.area.height:
            self.speed[1] = -self.speed[1]

class Main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.setup()
    def setup(self):
        pygame.init()
        size = (self.width, self.height) = (640,360)
        self.black = (0, 0, 0)
        self.bg = pygame.image.load(bg)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, 0, 32)
        self.toon = Toon()
        self.setup_background()
    def setup_background(self):
        self.background = pygame.Surface(self.screen.get_size())
        self.background = self.background.convert()
        self.screen.blit(self.bg, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()
    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.bg, (0, 0))
        self.screen.blit(self.toon.image, self.toon.rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
    def event_loop(self):
        toon = self.toon
        friction = 1        
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    deltax, deltay = delta.get(event.key, (0, 0))
                    toon.speed[0] += deltax
                    toon.speed[1] += deltay
                    friction = 1
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    friction = 0.95
            toon.speed = [x*friction for x in toon.speed]
            toon.update()
            self.draw()
            pygame.time.delay(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Main()
    app.event_loop()
```

Comment: that is absolutely beautiful thanking you both so very kindly. I've been trying to work this out during my spare time when I'm not studying and was scratching my head over it quite a bit. kudos to the both of you <3